# Splunk HTTP Event Collector - Why does my Time field have 000 milliseconds?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm getting data into Splunk by using: HTTP Event Collector
I'm using Splunk Enterprise 8.0.1

My Time field is missing milliseconds:
18/08/2021 18:36:37.000

My Splunk record:
Time _time 2021-08-18T18:36:37.000+00:00

Answer (score 1):

The `_time` field is stored in Unix epoch format - ie in whole seconds

Here is a relevant post from /r/Splunk that goes into the format of bucket names (and Unix epoch timestamps) - https://www.reddit.com/r/Splunk/comments/osrcr6/is_splunk_the_best_option_for_storing_data/h6r8vw7

And the Docs.Splunk citation from that post: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Indexer/HowSplunkstoresindexes#Bucket_naming_conventions